# JavaScript use of pubnub.time() - code carries on before setting value

Tags: javascript, ajax, time, pubnub

I am having an interesting issue getting client-side JavaScript and pubnub's time() to act as I want.

```
function myFunc(){

    pubnub.time(
        function(time){
            window.timeNow = parseInt(time / 10000000)
        }
    )

    pubnub.publish({
        'channel' : "someChannel"
        'message' : "json" + window.timeNow + "more-json"
    })

}
```

This code is called every NN seconds.

- The first call to this code sends timeNow as undefined.
- The next call to this code sends timeNow as the previous time!
- The next call to this code sends timeNowas the previous time ....

`pubnub.time()` is doing the correct thing, but code carries on and executes `pubnub.publish()` before `pubnub.time()` has time to set the current time value.

Is there a way round this issue.  ...Without creating an artificial sleep(3000) to give it time to return.

And I can't do the dirty fix of `timeNow = timePrevious + NN`  because it is not always the same NN.  Which is a pity ;)

The back story is that I want to check timely arrival of messages at my server, so I am using `pubnub.time()` at both ends and comparing:

```
if (message-timestamp - current-time > a few seconds): # ignore this message as too old
```

I can't rely on client-time being in synch with the world, and I do need it to be by a few seconds, which is why I'm using pubnub.time() both ends.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `pubnub.publish` inside the `pubnub.time`:

```
function myFunc(){

    pubnub.time(
        function(time){
            window.timeNow = parseInt(time / 10000000)
            pubnub.publish({
                'channel' : "someChannel"
                'message' : "json" + window.timeNow + "more-json"
            })
       }
    )

}
```

I this way, the `publish` step will only be run after `window.timeNow` has been set.

Comment: Thanks Paul,  That does work.  However, I have a load of other processing going on calculating a bunch of other stuff to go in the json string.  Wrapping a bunch of other code and .publish inside the .time seems quirky.  And looks inelegant.  I was hoping for some wait-for-ready possibility a la AJAX.  Perhaps something like .readyState=4 on the function call returning.  ... But thanks for your input, I have it working now, am happy :)